# Problema de datas em PHP (SELECT)

Tags: sql

Boa tarde! Tenho uma dúvida de PHP! Eu tenho um código para mostrar todos os campos de uma tabela onde a data seja 2018.

```
$sql_manutencao = 'SELECT * FROM manutencao WHERE data_trabalho LIKE "2018%" AND cod_utilizador ='.$id;
```

O código está a funcionar perfeitamente mas eu gostava de fazer com que a condição da data de 2018 seja automática! Mas apenas para o ano de 2018!

Eu quero que de alguma forma a data que eu meto no LIKE tanto dê para o formato dd-mm-yyyy como para o formato yyyy-mm-dd Mas sem utilizar LIKE "%2018%"

Aviso também que não sou eu que estou a gerir a BD e que pode estar sujeita a alterações regularmente!

Caso seja preciso mais alguma informação basta dizer que eu altero o código. Obrigado!

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "automática"? Quer que `data_trabalho` seja sempre `2018`? Se for o caso, poderia usar `EQUAL "2018"` ao invés de `LIKE`.

Comment: Como assim? Não entendi sua dúvida,

Comment: Se está a funcionar perfeitamente, o que pretende mudar? O que quer dizer com "data seja automática mas apenas para 2018"? Se é apenas para 2018, o que seria o "automática"?

Comment: Eu quero que de alguma forma a data que eu meto no LIKE tanto dê para o formato dd-mm-yyyy como para o formato yyyy-mm-dd
Mas sem utilizar LIKE "%2018%"

Comment: Mas a data no banco não estará sempre no mesmo formato?

Comment: Não propriamente! Quem gere a BD não sou eu! E pode estar sujeita a alterações regularmente!

Comment: Qual o tipo de dado do campo data_trabalho?

Comment: Sua dúvida não é sobre PHP e sim sobre SQL, você poderia informar qual SGBD? MySQL, PostgreSQL... Se for um dos anteriores dê uma olhada na função [`YEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) do MySQL e [`EXTRACT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) do PostgreSQL.

Comment: A minha SGBD é MySQL e o tipo de dado do campo data_trabalho é "date"
Mas futuramente será para utilizar num servidor público

Comment: Se o campo é do tipo date então utilize YEAR(sua_data) para pegar apenas o ano, independente do formato de exibição ser dia/mês/ano, mês/dia/ano ou ano-mês-dia.

Comment: ok! obrigado! ficou resolvido!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?
    $data = "13/05/2019";

    $data = explode("/",$data);

    if( strlen($data[0]) == 2 )
    {
        // este comando abaixo irá inverter a data em caso de um formato ou outro.
        $data = array_reverse($data);
    }

    $data = date('Y',strtotime(implode("/",$data)));

    $sql_manutencao = "SELECT * FROM manutencao where date_format(data_trabalho,'%Y') = '$data' AND cod_utilizador =".$id;
```

Comment: poderei colocar apenas o ano ao invés da data completa? Porque na verdade eu só quero o ano mas o meu problema está que a data na BD está como formato "date" ou seja está com o formato de yyyy-mm-dd mas eu quero fazer a seleção por ano!

Comment: Alterei o código acima. Você pode passar tanto data dd/mm/yyy ou yyyy/mm/dd que na query será comparado somente o ano.

Comment: Agradeço imenso a sua ajuda mas continua sem dar... eu coloco a data 13/05/2018 e não mostra nada sendo que eu tenho um utilizador com a data 13/05/2018

Comment: Adicionei o date_format, tinha esquecido.

Comment: Já deu agora! Obrigado pela ajuda!